# How to compare and remove x-coordinates (and the associated y-coordinates) that are less than previous x-coordinates?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, programming, pattern-matching

I am using *Mathematica* version 9.0 and am trying to compare and remove x-coordinates, and the associated y-coordinate, that are less than previous x-coordinates. Below is an example using sample data.

Raw data:

```
{{611.011, 1008}, {611.062, 1077}, {611.114, 1193}, {610.958, 894}, {611.009, 1621}, 
 {611.061, -166}, {611.112, 704}, {611.164, 131}, {611.215, 1306}, {692.637, 6394}, 
 {692.688, 6369}, {692.739, 6664}, {692.328, 6790}, {692.379, 7378}, {692.431, 5761}, 
 {692.482, 6750}, {692.533, 6348}, {692.584, 7535}, {692.635, 7365}, {692.686, 7725}, 
 {692.737, 7553}, {692.788, 8649}, {692.839, 8649}, {692.89, 7553}}
```

Desired outcome:

```
{{611.011, 1008}, {611.062, 1077}, {611.114, 1193}, {611.164, 131}, {611.215, 1306}, 
 {692.637, 6394}, {692.688, 6369}, {692.739, 6664}, {692.839, 8649}, {692.89, 7553}}
```

I tried using the suggestion from the answer to the question below, but could not get the code to work properly.

[Removing an ordered pair from a list of ordered pairs if the second element in the list is Less than a Value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15381/removing-an-ordered-pair-from-a-list-of-ordered-pairs-if-the-second-element-in-t)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please include in your question the exact code you are using that does not work properly.

Comment: Am I missing something? There's elements in the result that aren't in the target... that said, removing them (last 2 in desired result example), this gets the result I think you're after: `Cases[rawdata, {Alternatives @@ FoldList[Max, rawdata[[All, 1]]], _}]`

Comment: Thanks for finding my mistake, I fixed it in my question. Your suggestion worked though. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnHoulihan: No worries, glad it helped. n.b.: If your lists are much larger than the example, might want to insert a `Union` (`Alternatives @@ Union@FoldList[Max, rawdata[[All, 1]]]`) - this will speed things up, since duplicate alternatives need not be checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
r1 = Pick[r, Thread[# >= FoldList[Max, #]]] &@r[[All, 1]]

ListLinePlot@r1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Well, +1, if only for the spectacular graphics ;-)

Comment: @ciao `ListLinePlot[r1[[All, 1]], Axes -> False]` :P

Answer (score 3):

As an afterthought to my comment - if speed is important, this should handily beat existing answers, particularly on larger cases:

```
Fold[If[#2[[1]] < #1[[-1, 1]], #1, Append[#1, #2]] &, {First@rawdata},Rest@rawdata]
```

and this will be even faster:

```
FixedPoint[Pick[#, UnitStep@Differences[Prepend[#[[All, 1]], 0]], 1] &, rawdata]
```

finally, fastest I've come up with for larger lists:

```
rawdata[[Union@FoldList[Min, Reverse@Ordering[First@Transpose@rawdata] //
                     #[[;; First@Pick[Range@Length@#, #, 1]]] &]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ReplaceRepeated` (`//.`)

```
data1 = {{611.011, 1008}, {611.062, 1077}, {611.114, 1193}, {610.958, 
    894}, {611.009, 1621}, {611.061, -166}, {611.112, 704}, {611.164, 
    131}, {611.215, 1306}, {692.637, 6394}, {692.688, 6369}, {692.739, 
    6664}, {692.328, 6790}, {692.379, 7378}, {692.431, 5761}, {692.482, 
    6750}, {692.533, 6348}, {692.584, 7535}, {692.635, 7365}, {692.686, 
    7725}, {692.737, 7553}, {692.788, 8649}, {692.839, 8649}, {692.89, 7553}};

data2 = data1 //. ({s___, {x1_, y1_}, {x2_, _}, f___} /; x2 < x1) :>
   {s, {x1, y1}, f}
```

> {{611.011, 1008}, {611.062, 1077}, {611.114, 1193}, {611.164, 131},
>   {611.215,    1306}, {692.637, 6394}, {692.688, 6369}, {692.739, 6664},
>   {692.788,    8649}, {692.839, 8649}, {692.89, 7553}}

Comment: This is approx. 10 times slower than the [solution by belisarius](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89936/18476), even for this small sample data.

Comment: @Karsten7. - Starting with a fresh kernel and with this small sample my solution is faster on my system (Mma 10.2 on Mac OS 10.10.4). Although I certainly agree that it does not scale well.

Comment: I'm using Mma 10.2 on Win 10. Measured by `RepeatedTiming` this is 8 times slower and measured by `AbsoluteTiming` it's 5 times slower (independent of kernel freshness).

Comment: @Karsten7. - I made a mistake. Recheck with `AbsoluteTiming` showed mine as 4.4 times slower. Sorry.